# what models/OS of BlackBerry phones widely used in the world?

Tags: blackberry

I want to develop a BlackBerry Application.
but i am somewhat confuse bcoz there are a lots of models/OS available in BlackBerry phones.
So can any one have any idea/servey that the most popular model/OS in BlackBerry phones.

So i can develop a application for as many users as possible...

or tell me if any generalize sollution is available...

Thanking in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you haven't done so already you should visit :

http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/

Java seems to be the development standard on BlackBerry phones

> Java 5.0 : The new gold standard for
>   Java® development on the BlackBerry
>   Application Platform.

You'll get all the information you need on their developers' site.

They also provide simulators per blackberry model.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The 8520 is the #1 BlackBerry handset in South Africa. I guess it depends on the country.

Have a look at [Admob's Metrics](http://metrics.admob.com/) that they release detailing different top handsets in different segments.
WorldWide it's: BlackBerry 8700, BlackBerry 8100 and then the BlackBerry 8830 according to their data.

Also check Opera Mini's stats.